# Access custom TableViewCell superclass NIB

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have custom UITableViewCell class with `.xib` and `.swift` file. Then i want to subclass from it, but only the `.swift` because i have the exact same view, but only different method to configure it.

I try to call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(superclassIdentifier) as! subclass`, but it generate error `could not cast value of type superclass to subclass`.

How to do it correctly?

Comment: have you registered the nib?

Comment: @SubinKKuriakose, yes i already register it with `tableView.registerNib(superclass.nib, superclass.identifier)`. If I register it with `tableView.registerClass(superclass.class, superclass.identifier)` i got error indicate that IBOutlet on superclass is nil, I already double-check it that i connect the superclass.xib and superclass.swift correctly

Comment: you can't do that cast in swift . if they are exact same view why you need a `subclass` ?

Comment: @WilsonXJ, Imagine i have cell with a lot of same `custom label` at the exact same position, but i have a lot of view that will configure those `custom label` differently. For example, 1. the font need to change, 2. the format need to change. So i subclass those cell without recreating the cell xib. Or this is not the best practice?

Comment: @F.Suyuti the problem is about how you config the cell.you can easy change it by config funcs .

Comment: @WilsonXJ, yeah sure, but i have a lot of differences on each configuration, for now i just add as much as methods to config it's view. But i thought if i can subclass it then i can easily manage it in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @F.Suyuti if you really want a `subclass` to do this ,change `xib` to code init ,the nib gives an instance the `ClassName` you write in `xib` .

Answer (score 0):

You should set all iBoutlets object as File's Owner instead of class name.Now i think you connected to same class name.